# Bitnami - Connecting with two computers on one host

Tags: wordpress, localhost, bitnami

I'm having a problem with bitnami. What i would want to do is to connect with my laptop to the bitnami localhost where my wordpress is at. But it doesnt seem to work on my laptop. It works on my stationary computer where the bitnami is installed at.

Stationary computer is windows 10, and my laptop has MacOS because it's an apple laptop.

If you need more information about my setup please ask me!

Answer (score 1):

> What i would want to do is to connect with my laptop to the Bitnami localhost where my Wordpress is at.

Do you have both your laptop and your "stationary compute" on the same private network? If so, you need to open the port 80 on the Windows firewall on the "stationary compute" so you allow remote connections to it. Then, you just need to use the internal private IP of the stationary compute to connect from the laptop.

More information in the link below:

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/faq/windows-faq/#how-to-open-ports-for-remote-access